# Call external api in laravel with queue

Tags: php, api, laravel-5, queue, laravel-queue

I am trying to develop site like insurance but I am stuck at one position like after taking input data from user I want to pass those input to multiple different external api and get those all api response on to page but if one of api response fails whole process fails and I also don't want to user to wait for too long. I was thinking of doing with queue but don't how to get response from queue. I even try to set up gearman but it's too complicated to work on. Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try with Queue Job chaining..so that ur jobs will get dispatched sequentially..

To get ACK for API is being failed or success, create an callback API which will be hit when your queue object is dispatched with required statues..and can write logic whatever you are willing to.

I hope this will help to some extent..

Comment: Can you create one example how it will look like?? Should should I call api inside handle method of queue or what?

Comment: Will provide you example shortly.. yes can give a call to API..with required requests from queued up function..

Comment: But after dispatch job how to get api response value??